# Inputting a string containing greek characters in linux

Tags: c++, linux, vim

I have a function which returns a string.
I have to define that string with greek characters in the function itself and should return that string.
I am working on Linux platform and my code is in C++.

My function is as follows:

```
string gen_string()
{
  string str = "αγρω";
  return str;
}
```

But I am not able to give the input.
When I try to copy paste the greek characters I want, it is appearing as some garbage characters.

Can some one please help me with this?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**:
Thanks for all your response.

Its not about using the wstring or string.
When I copy the string to the vim to give it as input, it is appearing as something like this.

▒~^▒~T▒~A▒~A201604¸▒~B▒žMDF_F▒~S123▒~T▒~B▒▒~B▒

I also tried by keeping the text in the file and opening the text file from vim.
But still it's the same.

Comment: This seems to be more of an IDE question.

Comment: Is there a reason why you're not using `wstring` and wide literals?

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? Are you unable to create a source file whuch contains Greek characters?

Comment: So the problem is in vim, not in any program you wrote, right?

Comment: yes! I am not able to copy the string as it is in the vim.

Comment: So the C++ tag is irrelevant, and the question is borderline offtopic. You may have better luck asking it on http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

`string` is only for ASCII characters, I believe.

You have international, likely Unicode characters. Consider using `std::wstring` for a multibyte "wide" string.

Comment: Not necessarily, see utf8.

Comment: You are mixing up binary storage and semantics of the stored contents. Both `std::string` and `std::wstring` (or `std::basic_string` in general) can only *store* Unicode characters; they are not aware of any semantics, which becomes obvious as soon as you try operations like `substr`, `operator[]`, `length` and so on. `std::string` is safe for ASCII because every ASCII character is guaranteed to fit in a `char`, which means that for ASCII, a storage element equals a semantic character element.

Comment: Right, but would using wstring not then select method and operator overloads that know how to deal with multibyte characters? I haven't dealt with this in a while so my memory is a bit rusty.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean copy from some text to the terminal input then how to do this depends on the terminal. If it's a gnome terminal you need to specify UTF-8 in the locale settings though I'm not sure if that would get you the Greek alphabet.

locale command will list the current locale setting in locale.conf. You likely want to change the LANG setting. A way to do this system wide is

localectl set-locale LANG=en_country_code.UTF-8

Change country_code. It's US for the United States but I don't know what the Greek code is. You may need to be root. To change it just for yourself modify

~/.config/locale.conf 
(or $XDG_CONFIG_HOME/locale.conf or $HOME/.config/locale.conf).

whichever gets you to the locale.conf file. On most systems all of them do.